# C++ pointer with c-style string

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings, cout, memory-address

Why i don't get the address when cout the pointer ?
See the code below:
code1:

```
string s1 {"NAME"};
string *p1 {&s1};
cout<<p1;
```

gives 0x71fcc0 which makes sense.
But see what happens when i use cstyle string:

```
char cstring1 [] {"NAME"};
char *cp2 = &cstring1[0];
cout<<cp2<<endl;
```

Prints NAME on the screen
So why it doesn't print an address ?

Comment: cout has a lot of overloads and when it sees a `char*` it assumes a C style string and prints it.

Comment: Technically it's `operator<<` that has the overloads, not `cout`, but the point is the same.

Comment: If you want address in the last case, simply cast it to `void *` and print its value.

Comment: Do you really want `cout << "hello" << endl;` to print out the address at which the string "hello" is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So why it doesn't print an address ?

Because it is a pointer to `char`. And pointers to chars are treated differently from other pointers when inserted into a character stream.

When pointer to char is inserted into a character stream, the pointed string is produced, rather than the address. If the pointed string is not null terminated, then behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, `const char*` is treated as a character sequence, not as a pointer.

If you want to print the address, you can try this:

```
cout<< static_cast<void*>(cp2) <<endl;
```